# How to use <md-error> in Angular Material 2?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I am trying to display an error message when a required input is not valid in Angular Material 2. There is an example in the [Angular Material demo app](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/demo-app/input/input-demo.html) :

```
<form novalidate>
  <h4>Inside a form</h4>

  <md-input-container>
    <input mdInput name="example" placeholder="example"
      [(ngModel)]="errorMessageExample3" required>
    <md-error>This field is required</md-error>
  </md-input-container>

  <button color="primary" md-raised-button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jljFc.png)

Unfortunately when I try to do the same, I get :

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
'md-error' is not a known element:
1. If 'md-error' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part 
   of this module.
2. If 'md-error' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' 
   to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
```

What am I supposed to do to use `<md-error>`?

Comment: have you added `<md-error>` in your module ?

Comment: No I have not, how do I do so please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you added `MaterialModule` to your appModule?

ie

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        ...
        MaterialModule
    ],
    ...
})
```

**Update:**

`md-error` is a new directive that hasn't been released yet (as of beta.2) it will probably be part of the next release, I guess. More information can be found here: https://github.com/angular/material2/pull/3560

Meanwhile you can use `md-hint`.

Comment: Yes I have, other Angular Material 2 elements work well.

Comment: The md-error directive is now available in Angular Material 2 1.0.0-beta-3.  See https://material.angular.io/components/component/input.